# Can't display a subview fullscreen size and landscape

Tags: ios, uiview, orientation, landscape, subview

I'm adding a subview to a view controller, whose dimensions are 1024(W) x 768(H).  My app is set to support only landscape in the plist, and yet my subview will always display in portrait orientation, its bottom disappearing off the screen.

My superview:

```
#import "TSTViewController.h"
#import "TSTContentViewController.h"

@interface TSTViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) TSTContentViewController *tcvc;
@end

@implementation TSTViewController

- (void)loadView
{
    UIView *rootView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1024.0f, 768.0f)];
    [rootView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    self.view = rootView;
    _tcvc = [[TSTContentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TSTContentViewController" bundle:nil];
    [rootView addSubview:_tcvc.view];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"H:%f W:%f; H:%f W:%f", self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, _tcvc.view.frame.size.height, _tcvc.view.frame.size.width);
}

@end
```

My app delegate:

```
#import "TSTAppDelegate.h"

#import "TSTViewController.h"

@implementation TSTAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[TSTViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

My subview (TSTContentViewController) has no custom code, and a nib with dimensions (1024W X 768H), with a gray background.

Seemingly unconditionally, the result looks like:

(yellow superview, gray subview)
[image]

The NSLog in viewDidAppear prints that both views have portrait orientation dimensions, even the yellow one, that actually looks like it is in landscape orientation.

Any ideas?

**Edit for additional detail:**

If the width of the subview is just one pixel smaller, the view goes landscape like it should (see thin yellow strip below).

[image]

According to my observations, only exactly fullscreen causes this subview rotation.  Smaller and larger frames preserve the dimensions defined in the nib.

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: TSTViewController (the superview) has no nib.  TSTContentViewController (the subview, gray) displays the same with or without autolayout.

Comment: Added a detail.  If the subview is smaller than 768 in height, it goes landscape as expected.

Comment: Please, check the answer I've posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you use autolayout then you just need to add couple of constraints for your subview:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    UIView *rootView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1024.0f, 768.0f)];
    [rootView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    self.view = rootView;
    TSTContentViewController* _tcvc = [[TSTContentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TSTContentViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:_tcvc.view];
    [_tcvc.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[view]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"view":_tcvc.view}]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"view":_tcvc.view}]];
}
```

Comment: Ok.  Any idea what to do if I'm not using autolayout?

Comment: You need override `- (void)viewWilLayoutSubviews` and layout your subview manually.

Comment: Hmmmm okay, I'll give that a shot.  Still, it's only at exactly fullscreen-sized dimensions that this happens.  Bug in the API, perhaps?